# Linux driver: example scatterlist usage for DMA/PCIe

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma, pci-e

Has anyone found an example driver that uses the new-ish scatterlist API (`dma_map_sg`, etc, for 2.6.26+)?

I have lots of disjoint documentation but no example code. I'd rather not have to download the entire kernel tree and search for drivers which may, or may not, use the API correctly.

After several hours searching for PCIe drivers I've got the Altera Avalon code, which doesn't do anything complicated and which is a great example of keep-your-code-propietary-by-not-commenting-it, and the Opencores pexdrv, which doesn't use scatterlists. I couldn't find anything useful at Xilinx. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Before I get any more close votes, "how to use an API" is a perfectly legitimate programming question, and if the only concrete example is code which is out there somewhere, then surely "where is that example code" is also a legitimate question.

Comment: If you consider 2.6.26 **+**, then best place to start is *Documentation* folder in your kernel source tree.

Comment: It should be similar to the older, PCI-specific, DMA scatterlist API (`pci_map_sg`, etc.), except that the new API takes a `struct device *` instead of the PCI-specific `struct pci_dev *`. So you could look for examples using that older API.

Comment: I have actually written a scatterlist implementation, but it was on 2.6.10 and was untested. 2.6.24 removed the `page` member from `scatterlist`, and changed the API. Some existing drivers in the tree were patched up at the time. The standard `Documentation` docs (DMA-mapping/DMA-API/DMA-API-HOWTO) are basically just discussion documents, with small unconnected code fragments, and no definitive documentation for individual calls. What is fundamentally missing is a complete working example.